Google Workspace, "Invalid Client ID" when adding Domain-wide delegation
I'm trying to setup a Service account to use the Google Calendar API on a website.
I'm mostly following this tutorial
I'm Super Admin on the Google Workspace Admin Console.
I created the service account as explained on the tutorial, but when I try to add a new Domain-wide delegation, I get the "Invalid Client ID" error. I can't understand what's wrong.


Something weird I noticed is that on the Google Support page about the Domain-wide delegation, it says that I'm not Super Admin.

But on the Google Workspace admin console, I clearly am.

I don't know if this could be related to my problem

Can you try to redo the steps and recreate the service account? If you still get the error, can you check if your account is present on the list of super admins? You can go to this link and then click on Super Admin. There should be a list of super admin users listed under admins assigned.

I checked on the link and I am correctly listed as a super admin.
I completely logged out, changed browser and I created a new service account (without deleting the first one)
I tried to add the new service account in the domain-wide delegation but the same "invalid client id" error appeared

That should work as far as I know. I have created a service account on my side with a domain-wide delegation. I used the same client ID for the service account I created to give it a domain-wide delegation. Is it possible that you have another non-admin account signed in? It is possible that the non-admin account is the active account for your current cloud console session.

I'm pretty sure to be logged with the admin user. I used a freshly installed Firefox browser in private browsing.

I see. Unfortunately, those were the only ideas I have. When I followed the steps from the site you referenced, I did not encounter the issue that you have encountered. Have you tried asking help from Google Workspace Support?

I just did, I'm waiting for their answer, Thank you for your help

The Google support answered me that it was apparently a known issue and that they were working on it:
" [...] it was reported that we have an existing issue when it comes to creating client ID when setting up Domain Wide Delegation. Our Product Engineers are working on it as we speak. [...]  "

i has same issue with invalid client ID error

It seems to be fixed now.

Yeah it's fixed now. It was a problem on the Google side
