Unable to add any client ID on Domain Wide Delegation
When I'm trying to add a client ID on the Google Workspace Domain Wide Delegation, i'm getting an error 'Invalid client ID'. I have tried with a client ID that is already here, and same error.
Does someone can explain this issue ? It seem we are many currently experiencing this issue.
Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78839023/google-workspace-invalid-client-id-when-adding-domain-wide-delegation Looks like Google has an issue. I have this issue too

Google support have now confirmed Domain Wide Delegation has been fixed. See the message below:
Current update:
At 2024-08-09 18:04 UTC (just now):
Hello there. First, thank you for opening this support case and validating that your organization was affected. I apologize for the disruption this has caused you. Fortunately, we have identified and resolved the issue - you should now be able to configure API clients in your Domain Wide Delegation settings...
Should you still be affected, please let us know and we will investigate accordingly.
Thanks!
